# Сортировка массива по названию (возрастание)

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Столкнулся с проблемой сортировки массива по названию, которые имеют вид "[111.10.1.1] Один", "[111.10.1.2] Два", "[111.10.1.3] Три" и т.д. Пытаюсь так:

```
function sortName($a, $b)
{
  return strcmp($a["title"], $b["title"]);
}
usort($array, 'sortName');
```

Но этот метод сортирует неправильно, как можно отсортировать массив в нужной последовательности исходя из значений в квадратных скобках, остальное не имеет значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = [
    ['title' => "[111.10.1.1] Один"],
    ['title' => "[111.10.1.3] Три"],
    ['title' => "[111.10.1.5] Пять"],
    ['title' => "[111.10.1.2] Два"],
    ['title' => "[111.10.1.4] Четыре"]
];

usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return strnatcmp($a["title"], $b["title"]);
});
```

Результат:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(21) "[111.10.1.1] Один"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(19) "[111.10.1.2] Два"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(19) "[111.10.1.3] Три"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(25) "[111.10.1.4] Четыре"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(21) "[111.10.1.5] Пять"
  }
}
```

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно, спасибо!